# Get address from PyCObject?

Tags: python, ctypes, python-2.6

I find it really strange that I couldn't an answer to this question by searching, only ever the opposite question on how to create a `PyCObject` from a pointer (and in C, not Python). I might just have used the wrong search terms.

I have a `PyCObject` in Python, and I want to get the wrapped memory address. Well, actually I want to convert it to a `ctypes` pointer, but I can do that from the memory address. How can I get it? `help(some_pyc_object)` isn't very informative and `dir(some_pyc_object)` isn't either.

I would like to do the following:

```
addr = some_pyc_object.get_memory_address()   # pseudo method
data = ctypes.c_long_p(addr)
# ...
```

Comment: @eryksun Yes, I've added the python-2.6 tag. Thank you, I'll try it!

Comment: @eryksun would you mind to post this as an answer? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [`PyCObject_AsVoidPtr`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/c-api/cobject.html#PyCObject_AsVoidPtr):

```python
import ctypes

PyCObject_AsVoidPtr = ctypes.PYFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.py_object)(
                          ('PyCObject_AsVoidPtr', ctypes.pythonapi))

addr = PyCObject_AsVoidPtr(some_pyc_object)
```